# EF6 query building to get the first object in the list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a `Car` class:

```
public class Car
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public List<Engine> Engine { get; set; } 
    }

public class Engine
    {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string EngineName{ get; set; } 
    }
```

And I want to create a select query which would look like this:

```
 IQueryable<Car> querybuilder = carDbSet.Include(x=>x.Engine);   // simple example
```

//this works

```
if(sunIsShining)
{
    querybuilder = querybuilder.Where(e =>e.Id == 5)   // all records where carId = 5
}
```

//this doesn't work

```
  if(windIscold)
  {
      querybuilder = querybuilder.Where(e =>e.Engine.FirsOrDefault().EngineName == "V8" )

   // e =>e.Engine.FirsOrDefault().EngineName value is null when in the db I have V8..
  }
```

I need to validate only on the first record of an engine despite the fact that relationship is 1 car to many engines.. how do I do this? should I somehow create a subSelect which would return only the first engine record?

Comment: you cant use FirstOrDefault in a where clause in linq to entities... this would work: querrybuilder.Where(c =>c.Engine.Any(e=> e.EngineName == "V8" ))

Comment: I have found a solution. You just have to sort using the first record when you get back all the data from the db.

Comment: Getting and mapping all data requires resources... memory and time to transmit all data...OrderBy with Take(1) or FirstOrDefault() is the obvious choice since this is translated to SELECT TOP 1 in SQL

Comment: Its not really good database design when you rely on the order of records... all rows should be dependend on the key, only the key and nothing but the key... so Codd help me...

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Any* if it doesn't matter which record is V8 for the car's engines:

```
 querybuilder = querybuilder.Where(e => e.Engine.Any(a => a.EngineName == "V8"));
```

If you definitely need to be the first row only, it'll get significantly more complicated.